# When calculating the time complexity of an algorithm can we count the addition of two numbers of any size as requiring 1 "unit" of time or O(1) units?

Tags: time-complexity, addition

I am working on analysing the time complexity of an algorithm. I am not certain what the correct way of calculating with the time complexity of basic operations such as addition and subtraction of two numbers is. I have learnt that the time complexity of adding up two n digit numbers is O(n), because this is how many elementary bit operations you need to perform during the addition. However, I have heard recently, that nowadays, in modern processors the time taken by adding up two numbers of any size (which is still managable by a computer) is constant: it does not depend on the size of the two numbers. Hence in the time complexity analysis of an algorithm you should calculate the time complexity of adding up two numbers of any size as O(1). Which approach is correct? Or in case the answer is that both approaches are "correct" used in the appropriate context which approach is more acceptable in a research paper? Thank you for any answer in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the kind of algorithm you are analyzing, but for the general case you are just going to assume the inputs to the algorithm being analyzed will fit into the word-size of the machine it will be performed on (be that 32 bit, 128 bit, whatever), and under that assumption, where any single arithmetic operation will probably be executed as a single machine instruction and be computed in a single or small constant number of CPU clock cycles regardless of the underlying complexity of the hardware implementation, you will treat the complexity of that operation as being O(1). That is, you would assume O(1) complexity for arithmetic operations unless there's a particular reason to assume that they cannot be handled in constant time.

You would only really break the O(1) assumption if you were specifically designing an algorithm to be performed on numerical inputs of arbitrary precision such that you're planning on actually programmatically computing arithmetic operations yourself rather than passing them off completely to hardware (your algorithm expects overflow/underflows and is designed to handle them), or if you were working down at the level of implementing these operations yourself in an ALU or FPU circuit. Then, whether multiplication is performed in O(n*logn) or O(n*logn*loglogn) time in the number of bits would actually become relevant to your complexity analysis: because the number of bits involved in these operations isn't bounded by some constant or you're specifically analyzing the complexity of an algorithm/piece of hardware which is itself implementing an arithmetic operation.